# Is it suitable for a large SNS site 's database entirely using mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, performance, database

I never really used mongodb, but it lacks relationship between tables, makes me feel uncomfortable. Before, when it comes multi-tables query, I will use join, but if I'm using mongodb, it seems all multi-collection query need using this way: query a collection, then query another using objectid. I don't know which one is better for suiting this situation, RDB or mongodb?

Comment: You haven't really described your situation at all, so we can't tell you which is better "for suiting this situation". Further, you can get the job of storing and retrieving data done in either way. You have correctly identified that they are very different systems, nonetheless they both store and retrieve data. So the answer is 42.

Answer (score 1):

> ... it seems all multi-collection query need using this way: query a collection, then query another using objectid.

This is pretty common in big RDBMS systems. if you have one computer filled with Customers and another computer filled with Orders, then you end up using this same pattern.

Both systems are using Btree indexes to lookup the appropriate data. From the servers perspective the JOIN method is just as expensive as the "query collection A / query collection B" method.

Honestly, most big systems put Memcache in front of the query. So you can end up doing a few Memcache queries followed by some SQL queries.

> I never really used mongodb, but it lacks relationship between tables, makes me feel uncomfortable.

The world's largest social network is currently operating on SQL technology, so it can obviously be done. Of course, IGN wrote their whole social framework on MongoDB.

So both technologies are suitable and both will have their trade-offs.

Comment: "The world's largest social network is currently operating on SQL technology". I wonder which social network you are referencing. Could you please clarify? I doubt this claim :)

Comment: Facebook actually maintains it's own version of MySQL (https://launchpad.net/mysqlatfacebook/). In fact, I have met a few of the engineers dedicated to it (*yes, they have dedicated MySQL engineers*). Now, to back what I said above, they also use a lot of Memcache, though they have basically abandoned Cassandra internally (AFAIK).